# Dynamic Bash Variables. When do they get their value?

Tags: bash, shell, variables

Let's say I have...

```
LOG="$(tail -n 1 /var/logs/sass/logs/style.log)" 
echo -e "$LOG".
```

When is the variable set: when it is *assigned*, or when it is *echoed*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command substitution (`$(tail ...)`) is executed when it is parsed by bash; even before the variable assignment is performed. (Consequently, it is legal to use the old value of the variable inside the command substitution.)

Answer (score 1):

When the variable is set. Suppose you had code like

```
LOG="$(tail -n 1 /var/logs/sass/logs/style.log)"
echo foo > /var/logs/sass/logs/style.log 
echo -e "$LOG".
```

Then `LOG` would contain the final line of the log file, not "foo".

Answer (score 1):

The questioner seems to believe that he/she is defining `$LOG` to match the *dynamic* value of `tail -n 1 /var/logs/sass/logs/style.log`
This is not the case - LOG is a perfectly normal variable that is set once, to the last line of that log file at the time the assignment is executed.

If you really to define want something dynamic, whose value is evaluated only when it is required, you could use a function instead:

```
LOG()
{
  tail -n 1 /var/logs/sass/logs/style.log
}
```

and then simply call it (as `LOG`) whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to test yourself:

```
echo foo >file
filecontents=$(< file)
echo bar >file
echo "$filecontents"
```

The output is `foo`, implying that the `$(...)` is executed when `filecontents` is assigned.